# Return to my app after calling the map app

Tags: windows-phone-8, application-state

I'm currently writing an app for Windows Phone 8, that conains some contact information and is able to open the bing map navigation to navigate to the contact adress.
My problem is that I want to return to the page from which I opened the bing map stuff by pressing the 'back' button of the Windows Phone.
I just don't get how i store that page before the Application_Deactivated method is called and how I can get it back when the Application_Activated method is called.
Here is the code part where I hand over the adress and open bingMapsDirection.

```
 bingMapsDirectionsTask = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();
 LabeledMapLocation spaceNeedleEnd = new LabeledMapLocation(client.street+","client.postalcode + " " + client.city, null);
 bingMapsDirectionsTask.End = spaceNeedleEnd;    
 bingMapsDirectionsTask.Show();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I just don't get how i store that page` It depends.  Hopefully you're using the root frame to navigate by URI -- that way the correct page in your app will be loaded when the user hits "back".  Then it's a matter of saving any state data:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Sorry for the late respond and thank you very much for the link it was very helpful.